# How to find a proprietary nvidia driver and a nvidia-modprobe with the same version?

Tags: nvidia, proprietary-drivers, modprobe

In order to enable the CUDA functionality of a GTX 1060 in Blender, I have to get 3 things in advance:

- NVIDIA driver
- CUDA toolkit
- `nvidia-modprobe`

The NVIDIA driver and nvidia-modprobe need to have the same version.

I can find different random versions of the NVIDIA driver and different random versions of `nvidia-modprobe`, but I am not able to find a couple sharing the same version.

Comment: looks like nvidia and nvidia-modprobe are available in the official ubuntu repositories.  assuming you are running an ubuntu variant, do those packages not work for you? and if you are not on a recent version of ubuntu, what OS/distro are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the desired version of `nvidia-modprobe` here:

http://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/nvidia-modprobe/

unpack it, then install via `make all` and `sudo make install`.

Also, you can work directly with the sources, available from the github repo:

https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-modprobe

... selecting the branch corresponding with your driver version.